# Pegando valores de um for

Tags: python

dúvida bem simples mesmo.
Tenho a seguinte lista:

```
fruits = {"apple":"123", "banana":"456", "cherry":"789"}
for fruit in fruits:
  print(fruit)
```

Como faço para no meu retorno apareça os números de cada?

Da forma que está o retorno é: apple, banana e cherry

mas preciso que o retorno seja: 123, 456, 789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voce pode usar o valor que voce ja conseguiu extrair como chave no dicionario:

```py
fruits = {"apple":"123", "banana":"456", "cherry":"789"}
for fruit in fruits:
  print(fruits[fruit])
```

ou pedir os valores do dicionario com `values()`:

```py
fruits = {"apple":"123", "banana":"456", "cherry":"789"}
for value in fruits.values():
  print(value)
```

Comment: Simples assim! Top! Obrigado

Answer (score -1):

Você deve imprimir assim:

```
print(fruits[fruit])
```